# Hash rate of the average PC/Top end PC

Tags: hash, hashpower

Hi I was wondering if anybody had any idea about what the hash rates are like with PCs released fairly recently. I'm sort of looking for figures to use for an average user if they wanted to use their PC to mine, and then a sort of best case scenario if you will of the hash rate of somebody who has a good graphics card etc. Any sources or information from personal experiences would be great, thanks!

Comment: You can't mine bitcoin with PC anymore, they are all too slow. Mining Alt coins possible.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I am aware that this is long past profitable, I was just making an article and wanted to show that with the current competition of ASIC miners (whos hash rates were easy to find) mining with a standard PC setup would return much less bitcoin than the cost of electricity used :)